# How to change or add Woocommerce thank you page URL key content?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, paypal

I have searched enough and I did not find an answer for this question but this may be a simple one.

In analytics, I want to set up goals for purchase and we have only 5 products, so each product purchase should be a separate goal.

The easy way to set purchase goal in Analytics is to **supply thank you URL**. Now, Woocommerce thank you URL includes important details in the thank you URL like below.

```
exampledomain.com/?key=wc_order_584a9caad78bc&amt=239.00&cc=USD&charset=windows-1252&cm={"order_id":13586,"order_key":"wc_order_584a9caad78bc"}&st=Completed&tx=2AF5736382483492L
```

This is how Paypal payment thank you pages are shown.

But when a user makes purchase directly on the site with gateways like 2checkout, moneris, stripe, I get the below URL type.

```
exampledomain.com/?key=wc_order_5849993d6ec72
```

As you can see above, this URL does not contain a lot of parameter for me to use.

**The question is, How do I edit these URLs to include product SKU?**

This way, it will be easy for me to filter based on SKU

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can edit the return url woocommerce provides to gateways by using the filter

```
woocommerce_get_return_url
```

some gateway plugins use a different method to get return url by invoking  $order->get_checkout_order_received_url() ; which applies the filter

```
woocommerce_get_checkout_order_received_url
```

an example would be like :

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_return_url','override_return_url',10,2);

function override_return_url($return_url,$order){

    //create empty array to store url parameters in 
    $sku_list = array();

    // retrive products in order
    foreach($order->get_items() as $key => $item)
    {
      $product = wc_get_product($item['product_id']);
      //get sku of each product and insert it in array 
      $sku_list['product_'.$item['product_id'] . 'sku'] = $product->get_sku();
    }
    //build query strings out of the SKU array
    $url_extension = http_build_query($sku_list);
    //append our strings to original url
    $modified_url = $return_url.'&'.$url_extension;

    return $modified_url;

  }
```

result url will be like

```
http://example.com/index.php/checkout/order-received/161/?key=wc_order_585214b2abb65&product_8=SKU1&product_45=SKU2
```

Comment: Dear @Mohamed,

Thank you very much, when I read your code, the logic seems to be good but when I tried, it, there is no change to the return URL. Also, there is NO error when I did a test order.

What could I be doing wrong? Can you please tell me.

Comment: @Dave I have seen some gateway plugins use a different method to get return url by invoking  which is
    $order->get_checkout_order_received_url() ;

which applies the filter
    "woocommerce_get_checkout_order_received_url" .

maybe you should try hooking override function to this filter instead , or check gateway plugin to find out which hook it uses to get return url

Comment: Would you please update this filter also in your Answer that way others can also find it.

Thank you so much

Comment: Glad it worked for you ,I have added that filter to my answer :)